# Connect to remote SFTP from Azure web site scheduled job

Tags: azure, sftp, winscp

I want to my exe connect to remote SFTP and dowload file from there.

In normal server I have used WINSCP everything was okay .

In Azure it is not working.

Any advice about what to use thanks

Comment: Is this an Azure VM?

Comment: nope it is azure web site.I have just create scheduled job inside it which every 15 minutes calls my console application.from that application i trying to connect to remote sftp

Comment: I have read that you should consider using Service Bus or Queue Storage Service to exchange messages with your application.   Azure and NAT is likely to create problems.

Comment: hmm we are talking different things.

Comment: what is not working ? you tried packing WINSCP as part of your job and it is not working? Also is the SFTP you trying to connect using a valid certificates which have no issues in the entire chain (I suspect that self-signed certificates would cause issues with certificate validation)

Comment: it is more logical I will check it .Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm getting the same error on Azure Webjob

Answer (score 0):

*"Not working"* is very vague. Please be more specific to get better answers.

Anyway, you maybe using an old version of WinSCP. Make sure you use the very latest WinSCP. There were issues with older versions of WinSCP, when running in the restricted Azure environment.

See also [SFTP/FTPS file transfers in Microsoft Azure WebJob](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_webjob_sftp).

Comment: IN WinSCP got this error : Server unexpectedly closed network connection.

As you said i am using older versions 5.7.X [as written in their site]

Comment: 5.7 is the latest released version. You are having a different problem. Please include a session log file into your question.

Comment: i am getting this error: [from local it works when i put it azure it gives me this error]

WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Server unexpectedly closed network connection.
   at WinSCP.SessionLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.SessionElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.CustomLogReader.TryWaitForNonEmptyElement(String localName, LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.CustomLogReader.WaitForNonEmptyElement(String localName, LogReadFlags flags)

Comment: *"Session log file"* please (use [`Session.SessionLogPath`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#properties))

Comment: a bit more explanation please

Comment: Set `Session.SessionLogPath` to a path, where you want WinSCP .NET assembly to store a session log file. Repeat your test. And include the session log file to your question (use "edit" link below the question).